# Cosine similarity between document of few tweets and document of thousands of tweets

Tags: natural-language, cosine-distance, cosine-similarity

I collected a **corpus** of $n$ tweets (few thousand) during a 48-period. The tweets were all collected based on a set of search terms. The tweets were published by $a$ authors, with $a \leq n$. Let's define the collection of all tweets published by the same author as a **document**, the smallest unit in my **corpus**.

Now I want to understand if it is possible (and makes sense) to compute the distance from each **document** and the entire **corpus**. I know that the cosine similarity of term frequencies it is usually applied between documents pertaining to the same corpus (eventually weighted to account for rare words). But how to proceed if I am interested in the 'originality' of each document compared to the other fellow documents of the corpus?

Comment: Don't think that the use of document here is appropriate -- each tweet is still a document. If you want to measure an average divergence in author styles, why not compute pairwise distances between each authors' documents, and scale by within author divergence?

Comment: @TC that just answers a different question

Comment: Also this could be a good use case for KL divergence.

Comment: @ssdecontrol You might want to elaborate on that? If you are referring to the deviation from the entire corpus bit, it is the same except now scale by all pairwise divergences.

Comment: @TC it seems the goal is to find "atypical" authors. Computing _pairwise_ author distances doesn't make sense to me here

Comment: @ssdecontrol The suggestion is to compute a distance of an author from another author or from the entire rest of corpus. Same principle applies. Compute pairwise distances and scale by dispersion within each of the two groups.

Comment: @TC wait, you mean the pairwise distance between tweets? How are you pairing them?

Comment: @ssdecontrol across groups of interest, scaled by dispersion _within_ groups of interest.

Comment: You need to define what is ``originality'' and come up with the features that can be extracted from each tweet.

Comment: @TC I could indeed calculate the pairwise distance between all authors and then average it for each. BUT then, with a corpus of only 5000 authors that would mean to compute 12,497,500 ($n(n-1)/2$) cosine similarities. I wonder if is not more practical to consider the whole corpus as a mean measure of the frequency distribution of terms and then compute a somehow weighted version of the cosine similarity between the 5000 authors and the whole corpus.